# Caret icon don't want to go next to Menu Item

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu, menu

I am having a menu, but my icon doesn't want to go next to menu item.

I worked while i had this code

`<li class="dropdown">
     <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-over="dropdown" href="partners.php">Partners</a>
        <span class="caret"></span>
     </a>
</li>`

I change it, cause I want a separate link when user clicks on link-menu-item and want to make my caret to work with drop-down, So ichange my to :

```
<li class="dropdown">
   <a href="partners.php">Partners</a>
   <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-hover="dropdown">
      <span class="caret"></span>
   </a>
</li>
```

I moved my `dropdown-toogle` with an `<a> tag` to the `<span class='caret'>` and now I have two `<a> tags` inside the `<li>` but the caret not coming next to text for no reason..

Any thoughts?

Here's a sample of my code

```js
$('ul.nav li.dropdown').hover(function() {
  $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeIn(500);
}, function() {
  $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeOut(500);
});
$('.dropdown-menu li a').click(function(){
     $(this).parents('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeOut(500);
})
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse btnCollapse"><div class="collapse navbar-collapse btnCollapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="partners.php">Partners</a><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-hover="dropdown"><span class="caret"></span></a>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu"> 
    <li>
     <div class="container">
      <div class="row">  
       <ul class="col-sm-4">
        <li><a href="partner.php?partner_id=106">Club</a></li> 
       </ul>                     
      </div>
     </div>
    </li> 
   </ul>
        </li> 
        <li><a href="login"><i class="fa fa-sign-in" aria-hidden="true"></i> Sign in</a></li>    </ul>
</div></div>
```

Hers a fiddle as well: https://fiddle.jshell.net/xjpt2p44/

Cause snippet display only in full mode

Comment: li.dropdown{display:flex;}

Comment: @Gerard yes that wotrk as well, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this css

`.nav .dropdown > a {
  display: inline-block;
}`